# Android - Unable to create new Intent which triggered from OptionMenu

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am new to Android development and currently stuck when trying to develop a simple app based on [This Tutorial](http://www.linux.com/learn/docs/686857--android-programming-for-beginners-part-2)

What i want is basically start a new intent when user click on a button via the setting menu (of the said app).

This are some segment of my code:

**MainActivity.java**

Here i am getting an error with SET_TIME_REQUEST_ID which is a constant that has not been declared anywhere in my code. Should i declare it, i am not sure what is the type of the constant and what value should i assign it with.

```
*** REST OF THE CODE ****

private void setTime() {
      Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CountdownSetTime.class);
      startActivityForResult(i, SET_TIME_REQUEST_ID);    
}

*** REST OF THE CODE ***
```

**CountdownSetTime.java**

The error i am getting with this part are; ***context*** and ***secondsSet*** cannot be resolved to any variable. Again, i am not sure what to do with this. Should i declare a variable called secondsSet? If yes, what is the type?

```
*** REST OF THE CODE ***

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.set_time);

      context = this.getApplicationContext(); // ERROR HERE.
      Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
      ArrayList<Integer> spinnerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      for (int i = MIN; i <= MAX; i++) {
        spinnerList.add(i);
      }

      ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(context,
              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);

      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

      spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
      spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
          View view, int pos, long id) {
          secondsSet = (Integer)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos); // ERROR HERE
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
    });
}

*** REST OF THE CODE ***
```

manifest.xml

I am absolutely clueless with this. I am not sure how could i register my new intent.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.gelliesmedia.countdown.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.gelliesmedia.countdown.CountdownSetTime"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName="com.gelliesmedia.countdown.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
             android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
             android:value="com.gelliesmedia.countdown.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Have you added CountdownSetTime in your manifest file ?

Comment: very good question. The answer to that is 'no'. I have editted my question so that it now includes my manifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read the tutorial you give as a link. That tutorial doesn't give the full code. According to what I see the variables you mention must be defined.

For `SET_TIME_REQUEST_ID` usually you add this at the beginning with something like that

```
private static final int SET_TIME_REQUEST_ID = 1;
```

because `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)`
That ID is your internal identification. I put 1 but you can put any number. It is an ID for you so that when the activity closes you can fetch the result.

So yes you have to define it.

Same for `secondsSet`.

The type seems to be `Integer` because the `parent.getItemAtPostion` is cast to `Integer`. It is used but not defined. Seems to me to be a global variable. The ones you put at the top of your class.

So yes you have to define it also :-)

And finally it is the same for `context`. It is used but not declared. It seems the tutorial you use declares all these variable globally.

**EDIT**

The manifest file tells the system that an intent (activity) exist.

You should have some thing like that

```
<activity
    android:name="com.gelliesmedia.countdown.CountdownSetTime">
</activity>
```

Comment: Thx.. i'll have a try. By the way i have edit my question with the activity registered in the manifest.xml

Comment: By the way if you read the questions at the bottom of the tutorial you will see that people ask nearly the same questions as you and you have also answers there.

Comment: Seems like someone also wrote a working code for all this https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1uF_SpOQUSYN1Budi1rdUJYVzg

Comment: in the link of the tutorial, if you read the comments, someone says he wrote a working example and I just copy/pasted the link he gives.